# How to call __iadd__ with 2 different optional arguments in python?

Tags: python, class

In my class data with the integers `n` and `s` it should be possible to add new values via `__iadd__` like this `d += 5` and like this `d += d2`

The first one would work with this

```
   def __iadd__(self, s):
        self.n += 1
        self.s += s
        return self
```

and the 2nd with this

```
def __iadd__(self, other="Data"):
    self.n += other.n
    self.s += other.s
    return self
```

But I can only have one `__iadd__` function in my class (right?), is there a way to merge these 2 together to make this function work with just a `s` input and also just another `Data` object as input?

Comment: You can use `if isinstance(s, Data)` and then change the behavior based on that.

Comment: What types are involved? If `s` is not another instance of `Data`, you might want to *create* an instance of `Data` from `s` first. That can either be inside the definition of `__iadd__`, or you can just make the caller responsible for the conversion.

Comment: What's the point of the default value? `__iadd__` can never be called without the `other` argument.

Comment: @Barmar I think they were guessing at a syntax that would mean "use this definition if `other` has type `Data`".

Comment: @Barmar why not? just `s` as 2nd argument works fine as long as long as I only call it up like `d += 5`. @Michael Cao this sounds like a good idea but how would the part x here have to look like? `def __iadd__(self, x):`? @chepner `s` is an instance variable of `Data`, I probably should have mentioned that.

Comment: The name of the parameter is irrelevant. `__iadd__()` is always called with 2 arguments, it will never use the default value of the second parameter.

Comment: Michael Cao's approach worked, this question can be closed, thank you guys. @Barmar Sorry you're right, pretty sure I meant to say `other: "Data"` instead of `other = "Data"`